# How much of the Amagi Brilliant Park light novel was adapted into the anime?

Tags: amagi-brilliant-park

Can you tell me how much the Amagi Brilliant Park anime adapted from the light novels, particularly in terms of which volumes?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I can tell you that KyoAni fairly extensively restructured and reworked the content of the light novels, as they tend to do with their light novel adaptations. The time limit for the park was significantly shorter in the LNs (two weeks, if I'm remembering right).

Comment: He's given three months in the anime. Having never read the original light novel, I don't know how that compares to the time limit it gives, though

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/LightNovels/comments/2rddl9/amagi_brilliant_park_does_the_ln_continue_on/ From this discussion, What I gather is that the main plot was that of the first novel, but some of the character development was pulled from subsequent novels, none of which were very plot heavy. Not posting as a answer since I haven't seen/read either

Answer (score 2):

The anime tells roughly the story of the first volume by expanding the deadline from two weeks to three months and by borrowing events from later novels. All of volume 2 was animated (hiring new staff and exploring Rubrum's cave), and the Kanie-body-suit incident was borrowed from volume 3.

NanoDesu Translations was DCMA'd and thus unfortunately was unable to translate the entirety of volume 3, so I'm afraid I don't have any more detailed novel-to-anime comparisons other than the fact that volume 3 did contain some story that the anime did not.

Answer (score 0):

If we refer to bakaupdates, the anime covers the first volume but differs after that by taking elements of various volumes. https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=119404